# How to return status code in Python without actually exiting the process?

Tags: python, bash, exit-code, sys, return-code

I'm trying to **return a status code without exiting the process** of my script. Is there an **equivalent to sys.exit() that does not stop execution ?**

**What I'd like to happen :**

If no exception is raised, status code is by default 0. **For minor exceptions, I want to return status code 1, but keep the process running**, unless a more critical error exits the process and returns status code 2 with `sys.exit(2)`. In my case, I'm looping through a bunch of PDF files and if one file has not been anonymised for some reason, I want to return status code 1 while looping through the rest of the files.

In other words, status code should correspond to :

- 0 - SUCCESS : all files have been sucessfully anonymised
- 1 - WARNING : at least one file has not been anonymised
- 2 - ERROR : critical error, interrupted process

For clarity : by *status code* I mean, what is returned by the Bash command `echo $?` after the execution of the script.

**What I have done :** I have tried using `sys.exit(1)` to handle minor exceptions but it automatically stops execution, as stated in the library documentation.

To sum up with code snippets :

For a given `main.py` :

```
import sys
import os

def anonymiser(file) -> Boolean :
    # Returns True if successfully anonymises the file, False otherwise
    ...

def process_pdf_dir():
    for file in os.listdir('pdf_files/'):
        if file.endswith('.pdf'):
            if anonymiser(file) == False:
                '''
                Here goes the code to change status code to 1 
                but keeps looping through the rest of the files
                unlike `sys.exit(1)` that would stop the execution.
                '''
            if criticalError = True:
                sys.exit(2)             

if __name__ == '__main__':
    process_pdf_dir()
```

After calling the script on the terminal, and echoing its status like so :

```
$ python main.py
$ echo $?
```

If indeed, at least one file has not been anonymised :

- Expected output (if no critical error) :

  ```
   1
  ```
- Expected output (if critical error) :

  ```
   2
  ```
- Current output (if no critical error) :

  ```
   0
  ```
- Current output (if critical error) :

  ```
   2
  ```

Hope this is clear enough. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You want streamed output, not return value. Print pre-determined strings to stdout.

Comment: I suspect what you actually want is some combination of an [exception handler](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html) and logging

Comment: No; while the process is running, your only way to communicate with the "outside world" is by writing to files (where a file could be on disk, a pipe, a socket, etc).

Comment: I don't know the python mechanics, but the running process could send a signal to the python process that python can trap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wait until the end of your loop to return the 1 exit code.  I'd do it like:

```
def process_pdf_dir() -> int:
    ret = 0
    for file in os.listdir('pdf_files/'):
        if file.endswith('.pdf'):

            if not anonymiser(file):
                # remember to return a warning
                ret = 1

            if criticalError:
                # immediately return a failure
                return 2
    return ret

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(process_pdf_dir())
```

If "critical error" includes uncaught exceptions, maybe put that outside of `process_pdf_dir`, e.g.:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        sys.exit(process_pdf_dir())
    except:
        sys.exit(2)
```

Comment: Your solution works just fine, thanks. What's clearer now for me is this : the only way I'm returning a status code is by stopping the execution of the script.

Comment: Yes; by definition the exit status is only returned when the script (or whatever process you're running) exits.  If you want to be able to send information from a running process, you probably want a socket or a file.